# Why is Chrome, version 75 calling the method twice for an action URL? I does not do this for earlier versions of Chrome or other browsers,

Tags: google-chrome, liferay

In Liferay, the method called for an action URL are called twice in Chrome version 75.

The problem started on June 3, the day Chrome version 75 was released.  This does not happen for a resource URL, earlier versions of Chrome or other browsers.

In the jsp, the action URL is
  /portlet:actionURL>
This is used as the action for for form POST method.
  " id="testForm">

The method for saveInfo, saves items from the screen in the database.  Every log message is shown twice.  Any item saved to the database is save twice with the insert time a fraction of a second different.

There are no error messages.

Comment: Are you sure? HAve you seen double call on the network pane od devtools?

Comment: I am not sure how I would see the double call in the network panel.  I know it is being called twice because a log message at the beginning of the method called by the controller is shown twice.

Comment: We are also experiencing the same -- recently (likely June) apace receives dual calls from chrome - even when submit button is blocked with a verify() query dialog. Any news?

Comment: One possibility is the calls to the server times out and browser retries. Maybe since june your/our service takes longer to respond?